# Установка пакетов в cygwin

Tags: установка, cygwin

Доброго времени суток!

Не подскажете, как установить пакеты в cygwin? Гуглю интернет, но что-то пока ничего внятного не могу сообразить. Вроде бы говорят, надо скачать с сайта, при установке setup.exe скачал все в папку, но там архивы типа `*.tar.bz2` , пробовал распаковать архив, распаковался он удачно, но вот в `/bin` и `/usr/bin` ничего не обнаружил, для справки, перл распаковывал, но ничего подобного в двух ветках не увидел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустить setup.exe. Выбрать пункт "Install from Local Directory" ...
Не то? А, кстати, что автор скачивал: бинарные пакеты или исходники?

Comment: автор скачал все  с оф сайта, и по ходу там лежат не бинарные пакеты , а просто архивы, в самих архивах я так и не понял что лежит, просто я распаковывал их, но вот он распаковывает, а потом нифига...

Comment: Ну вот, например, bash-4.1.10-4.tar.bz2 - бинарный пакет bash. Если такое - то натравить на них setup.exe (путём выбора нужных пунктов и указания директории в диалоге). По крайней мере раньше он умел брать пакеты и из общей свалки. Да, и зависимости пакетов никто не отменял, но вы говорите, что что скачано всё...

Comment: ну и бинарные пакеты компилить или что?

Comment: setup.exe пакеты распаковывает и, если надо, выполняет содержащиеся там скрипты.

Answer (score 1):

Установщик setup.exe запрашивает два пути - Root Directory и Local Package Directory.
Так вот в первой после установки и будут бинарники, а во второй как раз-таки архивы. А еще в меню есть ярлычок на RootDirectory/cygwin.bat. После его запуска консоль превращается в bash-подобную с корневой директорией Root Directory.

Comment: Только не bash-подобную, а bash (натуральный).

Comment: Так и есть. Сомневался.

Comment: так просто путь в локал директори указать?! попробую

Comment: Получилось?

Comment: да все получилось, странно, что при выборе установки через инет, он просто скачивает все, при повторной установке через директори все прекрасно встало

Comment: При установке через инет есть еще галочка Только скачать. Она случаем не стояла?

Answer (score 0):

Я всегда делал так.

- Скачиваю setup.exe
- Запускаю setup.exe
- Далее установку из интернета.
- Выбираю зеркало
- В появившимся окне выбираю нужные мне пакеты.
- Запускаю установку.

Comment: м, это то сделано, проблема в другом. он все скачал в папку , которую попросил выставить при установке ,  а там лежат тар архивы, причем банально перл интерпретатора нет в привичной для меня ветке /usr/bin, а уж тем более /bin, то есть получается, что

#!/usr/bin/perl
тролооло


ничего не будет, так как перла  то и нет, или он там прописался где то....

вроде решение есть собрать его gcc, тогда появится пресловутой perl.exe и все в порядке, но пока не пробовал